# How to make horizontal Listview Transparent

Tags: android, transparency, horizontallist

I have a custom horizontal listview ,what i want to make is transparent the background for horizontal listview,

i have added the following code too

```
android:background="#00000000" 
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

AND

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

I have used something like this..

```
public void setCacheColorHint(int transparent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }
```

could any body help me ,@thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using this

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

**Edit:-** Try to set the `setCacheColorHint(00000000)` of the `ListView`. You need not create a method yourself. `ListView` already has that.

Comment: that's a bit odd. This had worked for me, a couple of months back.

Comment: i have used customized listview...its different from basic listview right

Comment: in that case, try to set the background of the list items as transparent, along with the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Are the items populating the list supposed to be transparent?
If so you must make sure that their background is transparent.

Oh, and BTW `@android:color/transparent` == `#00000000` so it doesn't really matter which you use.